# Function application and reduction on large arrays

Tags: python, numpy, reduce, large-data

I have two numpy arrays, `X` and `Y` whose shapes are `X.shape == (m,d)` and `Y.shape == (n,d)`, where `m`, `n`, and `d` are non-trivial sizes. I need to make a third array `Z` whose shape is `Z.shape == (m,n)`.

An element `Z[i,j]` is the result of taking `f(X[i,k],Y[j,k]) for k in range(d)` and then summing over all `k`, for some ***non-linear*** `f`.

The obvious way to do this is to do this:

```
Z = numpy.zeros((m,n), dtype = numpy.float64)
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        Z[i,j] += (f(X[i,:],Y[j,:])).sum() # I can compose f from ufuncs
```

but what I'm really asking is whether there's some kind of clever broadcasting trick that I can use to compute `Z` that will:

1. take advantage of numpy's optimizations if possible
2. do this without putting an array of shape `(n,m,d)` in memory (`n*m` doubles will fit in memory, but `n*m*d` doubles won't)

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example of what may `f` look like?

Comment: I think there is no general solution by using only NumPy, however, you can use Cython or Numba to speedup the calculation.

Comment: @Jaime `f` could be `numpy.exp(-(X[i,:]-Y[j,:])**2)` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you don't want, I've included it because I believe this is the "canonical" solution to your problem.

```
# A simple function of x, y
def f(x, y):
    return 2*x + 3*y**2

x = x.reshape((m, 1, d))
y = y.reshape((1, n, d))
temp = f(x, y)
Z = temp.sum(2)
```

If you want to avoid creating the temporary array `temp`, which is quite large, you could try looping over the `d` dimension. In some cases the overhead of the following loop will be quite small and you'll get almost the same performance, with much less memory usage.

```
Z = np.zeros((m, n))
for i in range(d):
    Z += f(x[:, :, i], y[:, :, i])
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, actually that's a pretty elegant solution, it gets rid of some of the for loops that I was hoping to knock out. My real problem is slightly more complicated than the one I posted, but I think I can adapt this pretty well. I will post a note if it works out.

Comment: I told you I'd get back to you on how it worked out, and it seems to be working pretty well. Thanks again.